# Matplotlib: log scale for values too small for floating point

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, floating-point, sympy

I want to make a plot with matplotlib with really small values, shown on a log scale. This works fine until the numbers get too small and don't fit in a float.

I am representing values using SymPy arbitrary precision floats, but these are apparently converted to Python or NumPy machine floats internally in matplotlib.

For example

```
>>> import sympy
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> plt.plot([0, 1, 2], [sympy.Float('1e-20'), sympy.Float('1e-100'), sympy.Float('1e-700')])
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x11ac0c208>]
>>> plt.yscale('log')
```

Produces [image: plot]

What it should show is the third value at 10^-700 (not at negative infinity).

Now I have very little hope of getting matplotlib to use SymPy Floats internally (if it's possible, let me know). What I would like to do is provide matplotlib with the log of the value, which I can compute myself just fine, but still display the exponential of that value on the y-axis with a log scale.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the log calculation and then plot the data, if you want the same tick labels, you can use `FuncFormatter`:

```
import sympy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter

x = [0, 1, 2]
y = [sympy.Float('1e-20'), sympy.Float('1e-100'), sympy.Float('1e-700')]

def log_formatter(x, pos):
    return "$10^{{{:d}}}$".format(int(x))

formatter = FuncFormatter(log_formatter)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

y2 = list(map(lambda x:sympy.log(x, 10), y))
ax.plot(x, y2)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
ax.grid();
```

[image]

**EDIT**

To add log-scale minor ticks, you can create a `Locator`:

```
import sympy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter, Locator

x = [0, 1, 2]
y = [sympy.Float('1e-20'), sympy.Float('1e-100'), sympy.Float('1e-700')]

def log_formatter(x, pos):
    return "$10^{{{:d}}}$".format(int(x))

class LogMinorLocator(Locator):
    def __call__(self):
        majorlocs = self.axis.get_majorticklocs()
        step = majorlocs[1] - majorlocs[0]
        res = majorlocs[:, None] + np.log10(np.linspace(1, 0.1, 10)) * step
        return res.ravel()

formatter = FuncFormatter(log_formatter)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 8))
y2 = list(map(lambda x:sympy.log(x, 10), y))
ax.plot(x, y2)
ax.minorticks_on()
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(LogMinorLocator())
ax.grid();
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Comment: fun trick, you can decorate `log_formatter` with `@FuncFormatter` and then pass it directly to `set_major_formatter`

Comment: Does this use the logarithmic subticks like the normal log axes does?